# Assembly: Comparing input with string

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to compare a string the user enter, to a string i have predefined. I am having trouble because it never matches although it should, i write -r and press enter, try to compare it against a predefined string: rrr db '-r$' and it is not the same. Code below.

```
.model small                   
.stack 100h     
.data

data_from_file  db '.', '$'
file_handle     dw 0
file_name       db "helpDoc.txt", 0
welcome_text    db "To print only comments type '-r', to print only text press enter:",13,10,"$"
argument        db 3
                db ?
                db 3 dup(?)
rrr             db '-r$'
newline         db 10,13,'$'
msg1            db 'Strings are equal$'
msg2            db 'Strings are not equal$'

.code

start:          mov ax, @data
                mov ds, ax

vypis:          mov ah, 09h
                lea dx, welcome_text
                int 21h

                mov ah, 0Ah
                lea dx, argument
                int 21h

                mov ah, 09h
            mov dx, offset newline
            int 21h
            mov ah, 09h
            mov dx, offset argument+2
            int 21h
            mov ah, 09h
            mov dx, offset newline
            int 21h

            lea si, argument+2
            lea di, rrr
            dec di

lab1:           inc di
            lodsb

            cmp [di],al
            jne NotEqual

            cmp al, 0


            jne lab1

            lea dx, msg1
            mov ah, 9
                int 21h

NotEqual:       lea dx, msg2
                mov ah, 9
                int 21h
lab2:           mov ax, 4c00h
                int 21h             
                end start
```

I have tried various things such as editing my variables rrr and whatsoever to no avail, i cant seem to figure out what the problem seems to be. I am using GUI Turbo assembler

Comment: Did you try using the debugger to examine the buffer?

Comment: `cmp al, 0` assumes that the string is null terminated. I don't think code `0A` of `int 21h` says that it zero terminates. You need to look at the count of characters read (at `argument+1`).

Comment: @lurker As i mentioned above i am using GUI Turbo Assembler which doesnt have a debugging function.., in response to what you have said about the string not being null terminated i redefined the "argument" variable to 
`argument        db 3
                       db ?
                       db 3 dup(0)`

Comment: i have found a workaround, i have defined argument as i have said above, redefined rrr to `rrr db 13,0` and now i can compare against a enter = 13 in ascii